# Educational tablet mass-customization

Tags: customization

I am working on a small nonprofit project to bring educational tablers to rural areas of Thailand. I would like to ask you guys to help me out with the task. There are 100 chinese tablets donated. I am looking for a way to upload multiple educational apps at once and customize the tablet look and feel, so far I have found solution to upload multiple APKs with mass-apk-installer.

For customization I have found Themer, which unfortunately is not compatibile with the tablet. Then I came across Desktop VisualizeR this one looks promising, but customizing manually 100 tablets will be ages of manual work.

At the end I will have lets say 20 APKs with educational games. I would like to change the home screen so every one has different background and customized big icons, preferably 4x bigger than original size. The 'icons' should have custom descriptions. At the end I would like to fully customize one tablet and have some kind of solution to easily port all settings and customizations to rest 99 tablets.
I would kindly request specific answer to my problem, not links to general tutorials. Please help me out! The kids will grately appreciate your help.

Comment: Are the devices all of the same type (i.e. brand *AND* model)? What Android version is running on them?

Comment: Hi Izzy! Yes all tablets are identical 4.2.2 Androids

Answer (score 0):

As the tablets are all identical, and run Android >= 4.0, the following approach could be taken – provided all devices should be configured identically:

1. Configure one device the way you want to have them all
2. Use `adb backup` to create a backup of this tablet (see our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for a starting point if you didn't use ADB before)
3. Use `adb restore` to restore the created backup of the first device to all other devices

This should transfer all apps and settings from the first, manually configured device to all the others (including homescreen settings). You can play with parameters to `adb backup` to speed up the restore process, e.g. by specifying to only include the apps you added/modified, e.g.

```
adb backup -apk -shared -f backup_customized.ab com.package1 com.package2 …
```

(replace `com.package1 com.package2 …` with a list of packages you want to include). Skip `-shared` if you don't need to clone SDCard contents (you also could copy those separately, which even might be faster).